# Can my android TV launcher be visible when displaying settings?

Tags: android, react-native, android-tv, leanback

I have android TV app that is launcher and can open system settings. However, after opening settings my app stops being visible as on the image:

[image: android tv settings on launcher app]

Is there a way to see my app in the background similarly like when i open list of apps?

[image: list of apps on android tv]

I am using [react-native-launch-settings](https://github.com/DesignmanIO/react-native-launch-settings) to display settings.